# Ubuntu server 14.04 vsftpd connection problem

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I recently installed vsftpd according to this tutorial: http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/. I can login to the ftp but after that I get the following results from FileZilla:

```
Answer: 230 Login successful.
Commando:   OPTS UTF8 ON
Answer: 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status: Connected
Status: Folder list
Commando:   PWD
Answer: 257 "/"
Commando:   TYPE I
Answer: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Commando:   PASV
Answer: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,000,00,000,000). (I replaced the 0's)
Status: Server generated a passive answer with an untracable address. Uses the serveraddress instead
Commando:   LIST
Error:  Connection lost
Error:  Receiving folder list failed
```

(I have translated the above)

In `/etc/vsftpd.conf` I have the following commented out lines:

```
listen=YES
anonymouse_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_unmask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
chroot_local_user=YES (line #120)
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

allow_writeable_chroot=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=40000
pasv_min_port=40100
```

I have also portforwarded the following ports to the server:

```
80 protocol both: TCP UDP
21 protocol both: TCP UDP
22 protocol both: TCP UDP
```

I also did 22 because I have installed openssh

I hope someone could help me figure out why I get that error message.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post the complete output of `cat /etc/vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: @AzkerM I added all the lines that are not commented hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to open your passive ports

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 40000:40100 -j ACCEPT`

Then

`service iptables save`

Comment: I tried it but it's not working

Comment: By not working do you mean you're getting the same error or what? You'll probably need to open that range on your router as well

Comment: Oke I'll try that then but with a smaller range of 5